# DST adjustment error in iOS 7 Weather app?

Tags: ios, iphone

Is anybody seeing a DST adjustment error on their Weather app?
The time adjusted just fine (see top), but the times for other cities in my time zone (like Chamonix and Zermatt) have not been updated. Is this a bug (or a feature) or have I missed something?

iPhone 5, iOS 7.0.3, all location services for system services are off (switching on the "setting time zone" option makes no difference).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, this morning everything was sorted and correct! 
I did not do anything special, but my problem is solved...
Bjorn